# Django form changing required field depending on another field

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a django form InstellingenForm that has a few input fields. All should be required. But depending on the input of "spelmodus", either "tijd" or "woorden" should turn to required=False. (if "tijd" is selected in "spelmodus", the "woorden" form should change to required=False and vice versa) I tried to do this with a clean() function, but I can't seem to figure out how to exactly do this.

forms.py:

```
from django import forms

SPELMODUS = [
    ("", ""),
    ('tijd', 'Tijd'),
    ('woorden', 'Woorden'),
]

TIJD = [
    ("", ""),
    ('een', '1 minuut'),
    ('twee', '2 minuten'),
    ('vijf', '5 minuten'),
]

WOORDEN = [
    ("", ""),
    ('vijftig', '50 woorden'),
    ('honderd', '100 woorden'),
    ('honderdvijftig', '150 woorden'),
]

TALEN = [
    ("", ""),
    ('nederlands', 'Nederlands'),
    ('engels', 'Engels'),
]

MOEILIJKHEID = [
    ("", ""),
    ('makkelijk', 'Makkelijk'),
    ('gemiddeld', 'Gemiddeld'),
    ('moeilijk', 'Moeilijk'),
]


class InstellingenForm(forms.Form):
    naam = forms.CharField(label="Naam", max_length=10, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'input-container'}))
    spelmodus = forms.ChoiceField(label="Spelmodus", choices=SPELMODUS, required=True, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'input-container', 'id': 'spelmodus', 'onchange': 'hideShow(this.value)', }))
    tijd = forms.ChoiceField(label="", choices=TIJD, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'input-container', 'id': 'tijdClass'}))
    woorden = forms.ChoiceField(label="", choices=WOORDEN, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'input-container', 'id': 'woordenClass'}))
    taal = forms.ChoiceField(label="Taal", choices=TALEN, required=True, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'input-container'}))
    moeilijkheid = forms.ChoiceField(label="Moeilijkheid", choices=MOEILIJKHEID, required=True, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'input-container'}))

    def clean(self):
        if self.data.get('spelmodus', 'tijd'):
            self.fields['woorden'].required = False
        elif self.data.get('spelmodus', 'woorden'):
            self.fields['tijd'].required = False
        super(InstellingenForm, self)._clean_fields()
```

views.py:

```
def instellingenDatabase(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = InstellingenForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    rendered = render(request, 'instellingenDatabase.html', {
        'formulier': form
    })
    return HttpResponse(rendered)
```

instellingenDatabase.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'instellingen.css' %}">
    <script type='text/javascript' src="{% static 'instellingen.js' %}"></script>
</head>

<body>
    {% include "header.html" %}
    <div class="bodypage">
        <div class="settings-container">
            <div class="playText">
                Play
            </div>
            <form method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <table>
                {% for field in formulier %}
                    {{ field.label }}
                    {{ field }}
                {% endfor %}
                </table>
                <br>
                <button type="submit" name="Start" value="Start" class="button">Start</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You don't even use the form in the view other than passing it to the context? What do you expect to happen? At most you will be redirected to the url `/`...

Comment: I redirect to the url / only to check if the form validation works. If Start is pressed, it should redirect to /

Comment: You haven't even checked if the form is valid how do you expect that redirect to show that "the form validation works"? One uses the [`is_valid` method of the form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.is_valid) (on a _bound_ form in your case `form = InstellingenForm(request.POST)` in case the form is submitted i.e. the request is a post request) to check if it is valid. You haven't used it anywhere.

Comment: I have edited the views.py with the is_valid(), but I feel like I didn't do it correctly, cause 'formulier': form doesn't get the InstellingenForm

Comment: I have edited my answer do check it.

Comment: I feel like it should work, but it doesn't. It still doesn't redirect to `/`
Also can't seem to find where the print statements show

Answer (score 0):

Your approach doesn't work because the fields are *already* cleaned before `clean` is called. You should override `__init__` instead for these type of changes you may want to make to the form.:

```py
class InstellingenForm(forms.Form):
    naam = forms.CharField(label="Naam", max_length=10, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'input-container'}))
    spelmodus = forms.ChoiceField(label="Spelmodus", choices=SPELMODUS, required=True, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'input-container', 'id': 'spelmodus', 'onchange': 'hideShow(this.value)', }))
    tijd = forms.ChoiceField(label="", choices=TIJD, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'input-container', 'id': 'tijdClass'}))
    woorden = forms.ChoiceField(label="", choices=WOORDEN, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'input-container', 'id': 'woordenClass'}))
    taal = forms.ChoiceField(label="Taal", choices=TALEN, required=True, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'input-container'}))
    moeilijkheid = forms.ChoiceField(label="Moeilijkheid", choices=MOEILIJKHEID, required=True, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'input-container'}))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if 'spelmodus' in self.data:
            spelmodus = self.data.get('spelmodus')
            if spelmodus == 'tijd':
                self.fields['woorden'].required = False
            elif spelmodus == 'woorden':
                self.fields['tijd'].required = False
```

Also you never used the form in your view. You only passed it to the context and rendered it. You need to use the `is_valid` method if you want to check if the form is valid. You have added that in an edit but now you never make a form in case of a GET request, you need to do that too:

```
def instellingenDatabase(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = InstellingenForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print(form.cleaned_data.get('spelmodus')) # Check value of spelmodus
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        print(form.errors) # print errors here in case form is invalid
    else:
        form = InstellingenForm() # instantiate form in case of GET request
    rendered = render(request, 'instellingenDatabase.html', {
        'formulier': form
    })
    return HttpResponse(rendered)
```

Also when you render forms manually it is best to render the errors also as then the user can know what went wrong:

```
{% for field in formulier %}
    {{ field.label }}
    {{ field }}
    {{ field.errors }}
{% endfor %}
{{ formulier.non_field_errors }}
```

Comment: it seems like both woorden and tijd are still on required=True, cause if I try to use this, it does not work for me

Comment: @C.vanVeen what value do you specify for `spelmodus` in the form?

Comment: If you mean the value from the SPELMODUS choices, it's either tijd or Tijd I think, but I'm not too familiar with this.

Comment: @C.vanVeen If you have selected `Tijd` when submitting the form then `woorden` would have `required = False`. You say this does not work? What are the errors displayed by the form? Or what output does `print(form.errors)` give you? (write it somewhere so that it will run if `form.is_valid()` return false)

Comment: Where do I put the print statement?

Comment: Will it be useful if I add my template and view?

Comment: @C.vanVeen yes do add your template and view.